# How to transform the result of an iterator into an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, filtering

I want to know how to transform the results of an iterator into an array. I have presented two options below, and both run, but yield the result in the wrong format.

This is the result I am getting vs what is expected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WveP1.jpg)

I am trying to transform the iterator results into an array with `Array()`, but it does not work.

I tried:

1. Block code with `.keep_if` methods
2. for if conditionals with `Array()` to make the transformation.

What I expect:

An array of non-negative integers. The input (l) is an array of random integers and strings.

My code options are as follows:

Option 1:

```
def filter_list(l)
  l.delete_if {|li| li.class ==String || li<0}
  puts l
end
```

Option 2:

```
def filter_list(l)
  arr=[]
  for i in l
    if i.class == Integer && i>=0
      arr1=arr.push(i)
    end
  end
  puts Array(arr1)
end
```

Why don't the above options work?

Comment: What are you getting as a result?

Comment: They both [Work For Me™](https://gist.github.com/schwern/664a2a159338d8472bf965f4539a609e). 1) `Array(arr1)` is a non-Ruby way to write `Array.new(arr1)`. But arr1 is already an Array, no need to copy it. 2) Don't check `obj.class == Class`. Check `object.is_a?(Class)` in case it's a subclass. For example, `i.is_a?(Numeric)` will include Integers and Floats which all inherit from Numeric. 3) Your first filter function modifies the input which can be fraught.

Comment: Many thanks for your insight. Both options codes run, but the "format" of the result is wrong. What I am expecting is an array following this format --> [El1, El2, El3,etc]. What I get instead are the same elements, but in different lines...exactly as what you are getting.

Comment: I've added an image of my results vs what is expected from the code to aid your review.

Comment: For the expected output just use p instead of puts

Comment: `puts` seems to be messing with your return value. Not that although `puts l` will _output_ `l`, it will also _return_ `nil`. That `nil` then becomes the return value of your method. Have a look at [`tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-tap) which is a great tool to add debug output in an unobtrusive way.

Comment: @Panamaniac507 Is this homework? I think they want you to *return* the array from the function, not print it.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback. The solution was to use p instead of puts. Your argument is correct as well,

Comment: Please do not [edit] the question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Consider rolling back your question to [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74883406/2). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420044/2988, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351629/2988, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299405/should-a-question-edit-be-rolled-back-if-it-appears-to-be-a-follow-up-to-an-answ#comment221145_299405, and many others.

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't the above options work?

You have a syntax error here:

```ruby
Def filter_list(l)
↑
```

Method definitions use the `def` keyword with a lower-case `d`. What you have written here will be interpreted as a method call to a method named `Def`, passing `filter_list(l)` as an argument, i.e. that code will be interpreted as

```ruby
self.Def(filter_list(l))
```

Which then means that Ruby is not expecting to see an `end` keyword.

Comment: thank you for the heads-up, I made the correction in the post. The code has written def, not Def.

Comment: `def Def
  puts 'Raja'
end

Def` throws the following error ` `<main>': uninitialized constant Def (NameError)

Def
^^^` Why so?

Comment: `self.Def(filter_list(l))` Jorg you also have a typo :P

Comment: @Julian: I don't see a typo. Can you help me out and explain where you see one? I realize that in older Ruby versions, the two code snippets are not 100% identical, since `private` methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver even if that receiver is `self`. But that is no longer in true in the latest versions of Ruby, and there is nothing in the OP's question that suggests they are using an older version of Ruby.

Comment: @Rajagopalan: Questions should go in the textbox labeled "Question". The textbox labeled "Add comment" is for adding comments, not for adding questions.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Oh sorry I don't know that. Good that you told me otherwise I wouldn't have known this secret. Don't know how to say thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To output the result in the expected format just use `p` instead of `puts`.

From the docs of [`puts`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO#puts-instance_method)

> [...] If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line. Each given object that isn't a string or array will be converted by calling its `to_s` method. [...]

Whereas the [`p`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Kernel#p-instance_method) method doesn't call `to_s` but `inspect` before printing the output:

> For each object, directly writes `obj.inspect` followed by a newline to the program's standard output.

The default string representation, returned by `inspect` for an array, looks like your expected output.

Comment: @Panamaniac507 Please consider upvoting when an answer was helpful and accepting when the answer solved your problem. That is a way to say thank you and to indicate to other what answers were useful and that your question was successfully answered.